# How come when I make a small change I get errors saying things aren't declared? When they are

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, linker-errors, forward-declaration

I have a program that has 20+ class/header files. Everything was smooth sailing up until I started making some changes yesterday. It literally took me forever just to figure out that I needed a forward declaration on one of the headers. Although I had the same working yesterday and it wasn't using a forward declaration of the class.

I got it to compile and run correctly though. I tried to add ONE more method.. And I started getting all these freaking errors again! Like I said, yesterday all of this stuff was working, and somehow I made a single changed and kept getting errors saying "Creature has not been declared" even though I didn't change that class or anything.. along with that same error for other classes and other objects of those classes.

The headers are included in the files where it says the errors are - and I even probably added extra includes just to try it out. It's so frustrating and I spend hours trying to figure out how to get back to where I was yesterday.. And I try to simply add another function and the same thing happened!! Please help me resolve this continuing frustration. Here's the current error I'm getting:

```
g++ -c Ammunition.cpp -o Ammunition.o -std=c++0x
g++ -c Armor.cpp -o Armor.o -std=c++0x
g++ -c Consumable.cpp -o Consumable.o -std=c++0x
g++ -c Creature.cpp -o Creature.o -std=c++0x
In file included from DungeonLevel.h:4:0,
             from Creature.h:5,
             from Creature.cpp:1:
Tile.h:15:19: error: ‘Creature’ has not been declared
Tile.h:16:2: error: ‘Creature’ does not name a type
Tile.h:38:2: error: ‘Creature’ does not name a type
In file included from DungeonLevel.h:7:0,
             from Creature.h:5,
             from Creature.cpp:1:
Player.h:9:32: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
make: *** [Creature.o] Error 1
```

---

### Here are the Header files and Snippets where the errors are

**DungeonLevel.h**

```
#include "Tile.h"
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include "Player.h"

class Player; //This is how I fixed the error that took me all day when "Player" was not
              //declared. If you take it out, You'll get error "Player not declared"
class DungeonLevel {
public:
    DungeonLevel(int iWidth, int iHeight, std::mt19937 & randomGen);
    ~DungeonLevel(void);

    void dump();
    char at(int x, int y);

    void placeInGame(Player& playerToPlace, std::mt19937 & randomGen);
    int getWidth();
    int getHeight();

private:
    std::vector<std::vector<Tile>> m_vvTiles; //Tile was char

};
```

### DungeonLevel.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include "Tile.h"
#include "DungeonLevel.h"
#include "Player.h"

using namespace std;


void DungeonLevel::placeInGame(Player & playerToPlace, std::mt19937 & randomGen$
    int x;
    int y;
    do {
            y = randomGen() % 20;
            x = randomGen() % 79;
    } while (m_vvTiles[y][x].getDisplayChar() != '.');

    m_vvTiles[y][x].setCreature(&playerToPlace);
}
//Then other code that I don't think is needed
```

### Creature.h

```
#include "Entity.h"
#include "DungeonLevel.h"

class Creature : public Entity {

public:
    Creature(void);
    virtual ~Creature(void);

    virtual void dumpObject();
    virtual void dumpObjectData();
    virtual void writeFragment(std::ostream & output);
    virtual void writeDataAsFragment(std::ostream & output);
    virtual void setElementData(std::string elementName, std::string elemen$

    virtual void move(int dir, DungeonLevel & dl);

    virtual void setXLoc(int xToSet);
    virtual int getXLoc();
    virtual void setYLoc(int yToSet);
    virtual int getYLoc();

    virtual int getLevel();
    virtual void setLevel(int levelToSet);
    virtual int getHP();
    virtual void setHP(int HPToSet);
    virtual int getMaxHP();
    virtual void setMaxHP(int maxHPToSet);

private:
    int xLoc;
    int yLoc;
    int level;
    int HP;
    int maxHP;

    // Not worried about inventory yet...
    //std::vector<Item*> m_vInventory;

};
```

### Creature.cpp

```
#include "Creature.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include "DungeonLevel.h"

using namespace std;

Creature::Creature(void){
    HP = 0;
    maxHP = 0;
    level = 0;
}


Creature::~Creature(void){

}

void Creature::move(int dir, DungeonLevel & dl){
    //If I take the DungeonLevel & dl param. out.. I don't get errors
}

void Creature::dumpObject(){
    cout << "Creature:" << endl;
    dumpObjectData();
}
//The rest shouldn't be needed
```

### Tile.h

```
#include "Creature.h"
#include "Item.h"

#include <vector>

class Tile : public Entity {
public:
    Tile(void);
    Tile(char ch);
    virtual ~Tile(void);
    void setCreature(Creature * creatureToSet);
    Creature * getCreature();
    void setDisplayChar(char displayCharToSet);
    char getDisplayChar();

private:
    char displayChar;
    Creature * theCreature;
    std::vector<Item*> inventory;
};
```

### Tile.cpp

```
#include "Tile.h"
#include "Entity.h"

using namespace std;

Tile::Tile(void){
    displayChar = ' ';
    theCreature = NULL;

}

Tile::Tile(char ch) {
    setDisplayChar(ch);
    theCreature = NULL;
}

Tile::~Tile(void){

}

void Tile::setDisplayChar(char displayCharToSet){
    displayChar = displayCharToSet;
}

char Tile::getDisplayChar(){

    if ( theCreature != NULL ){
            return theCreature->getDisplayChar();
    }
    else {
            return displayChar;
    }
}

void Tile::setCreature(Creature * creatureToSet){
    theCreature = creatureToSet;
}

Creature * Tile::getCreature(){
    return theCreature;
}
```

### Player.h

```
#include "Creature.h"
#include "Weapon.h"
#include "Armor.h"
#include "DungeonLevel.h"

class Player : public Creature {

public:
    Player(void);
    virtual ~Player(void);

    virtual void dumpObject();
    virtual void dumpObjectData();
    virtual void writeFragment(std::ostream & output);
    virtual void writeDataAsFragment(std::ostream & output);
    virtual void setElementData(std::string elementName, std::string elemen$


    virtual int getScore();
    virtual void setScore(int scoreToSet);
    virtual int getXp();
    virtual void setXp(int xpToSet);

    virtual void setPlayerWeapon(Weapon* playerWeaponToSet);
    virtual Weapon* getPlayerWeapon();
    virtual void setPlayerArmor(Armor* playerArmorToSet);
    virtual Armor* getPlayerArmor();

private:
    //Creature provides level, HP, and maxHP
    int score;
    int xp;
    Weapon * playerWeapon;
    Armor * playerArmor;
};
```

### Player.cpp

```
#include "Player.h"
#include "Creature.h"

#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

Player::Player(void){
    setMaxHP(25);
    setHP(getMaxHP());
    setLevel(1);
    setDisplayChar('o');
    score = 0;
    xp = 0;
}


Player::~Player(void){

}
//the rest shouldn't be needed
```

---

Please help me, Thanks! Let me know if I need to supply more. Thanks!

Comment: Where are your include guards?

Comment: I have them. I just took them out to save space. Wouldn't the error message say if there were multiple declarations?

Comment: Time to read about include guards, circle dependencies and forward declarations

Answer (score 2):

You have circular dependencies in your includes. DungeonLevel.h includes Player.h, and vice versa. Due to the nature of include guards, one will always come before the other, but the order can swap with small changes.

You'll have to remove the circular dependency.

Comment: Grrr. Thanks. How do I go about that?

Comment: @ModdedLife A quick glance shows me that Player.h *does not* depend on DungeonLevel.h, so you can remove that include from Player.h. There might be others though, which you can find on your own.

Comment: So basically if I'm including headers that aren't needed for that class? And does the order of including matter?

Comment: @ModdedLife The problem is that they're circular - unnecessary includes usually don't cause problems. The order of includes does matter for circular includes: if the compiler starts with Player.h then it will see DungeonLevel declared before Player, which obviously is a compiler error.

Comment: how do I know what order the compiler goes in?

Comment: @ModdedLife you can run it through the preproccessor and not compile (on GCC use the -E option for this). Although you *shouldn't care* about the order.

Comment: Oh ok. I don't get how I fix it then. This is so frustrating. I keep reading stuff on how to properly use include guards and I can't get the errors to go away

Answer (score 1):

adding onto what @pubby as written. you should add include guards to all your files. to avoid the circular dependency issue.

`#ifndef _FILENAME_H_`

`#define _FILENAME_H_`

// everything in ur file goes here

`#endif // _FILENAME_H_`

where _FILENAME_H_ is the name of our header file.
that will insure even if you have a circular dependency that everything will only be included once. however circular dependency's can cause other issues when you need certain things included before others. thus circular dependency's should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I have them included, I just removed them to save space when adding the code. I'm still not fully understanding circular dependancies

Comment: when your compiler. compiles the code it starts on a file. and as it reads through it. it goes oh you want to include this file. so then it jumps to that file to dump it all infront of your code. so everything defined in it is above your code in essence. but then as it starts that file it see's ur include back to the original file and then you get stuck in an infinite loop. 

this is where include guards come in handy. because the compiler keeps track of every #define. so when it comes back to the file its already included it skips over it because the define is now their. does that help??

Comment: to just check. are your #includes within the include guards? 

also you can avoid including files if all you need is a forward declare. and then include it in the .cpp file. 

forward declaring everything and including it in the cpp. means if you make a library. you significantly reduce the number of header files that need to be included. which would allow you if u desired to ahve only 1 header. that forward declares every class and function available. and have the rest hidden and tucked away. (sorry for goign a ltitle off topic)

Comment: Yeah like I put #ifndef _DungeonLevel_included_
#define _DungeonLevel_included_

Then the header code.. then #endif

Comment: do you have a corresponding #endif at the bottom of your file. 

because your doing an ifstatement.

Comment: the #end if needs to be at the bottom of the file.

because then the code betwen the #ifndef and #endif will only get included once. but if its after the #endif then u still get circular dependencys...

Comment: ok well lets start by removing any includes not needed. 

from dungeon.h remove.
the incldue for player and tile. 

and forward declare tyle like you did player.

and then put those includes in dungeonlevel.cpp

remove dungeon.h from creatures header. its not needed.

Comment: and do the same for player.h remvoe all includes that dont have to call any of the functionality directly within that header file. 

you should in practice only include what you have to. and forward declare everything else. because it will get included in your cpp. or it will be included before that file is processed. this significantly reduces the chance of a circular dependency ever happening.

Comment: Ok thanks. Yeah I've never really understood how to properly include header files. And my professor just taught us about forward declaration a week ago. I forgot all about it since I've never needed it.